# how to calculate the execution time taken for the command cell in databricks notebook

Tags: scala, databricks

i need to know the time taken to execute the list of command cells in each notebook. Databricks displays the "command took x number of seconds" to execute . Similar to the displayed executed time , i need to capture the time taken to execute all the commands in a notebook.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following:

```
val startTime = System.nanoTime
// your code goes here
val endTime = System.nanoTime

val elapsedSeconds = (endTime - startTime) / 1e9d
```

Since you mentioned that you are a newbie don't forget that Spark uses lazy execution so the time to execute a cell that contains a transformation is not the true execution time.  Be sure to include an action to measure the true execution time.

Comment: Can you give an example to include an action to measure the true execution time of commands in notebook.

Comment: The simplest action is probably count(). It will return the number of Rows in a Dataframe.